# 2 people working on 1 HTML file simultaneously

Tags: editing, projects

My freind and I want to setup a collaborative project where we both work on a HTML file (and do PHP) at the same time (bit like Google Docs share feature). I want to be able to work with him to teach him certain things in PHP and HTML while I also code at the same time. Any suggestions? I have a VPS I thought we could use for it so nothings really going to get in our way. Maybe something like GIT or something?

Comment: Are you trying to get a desktop sharing type functionality where you two can edit at the same instant and can pass control back and forth or are you simply talking about a source control situation where you code, check in, he codes, checks in, if both of you were editing, you have to merge, etc?

Comment: Not particularly a desktop sharing thingy. Id like to be working with him along side him in a text editor or something so he can type and I can type and save our changes together.

Comment: OK, then you really need a real-time collaborative text editor. Here's [the list from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_real-time_editor#Real-time_collaborative_text_editing_software)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you need is a real-time collaborative text editor. Here's [an extensive list from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_real-time_editor#Real-time_collaborative_text_editing_software).

I use Google Docs personally but Microsoft has added this type of functionality into Office and there are a slew of desktop and online tools on that link. I had looked into Etherpad before but i don't remember enough to suggest one or the other. All of the links are on the wikipedia article so I won't repeat here.